# Does Firestore have internal mechanism to protect app from excessive $ charge from DDOS requests?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering if Firestore has internal mechanism to block requests similar to DDOS to prevent surprise surge in costs, or has a feature for owners to put limits on max requests/charges.

For instance, assume that there is a collection in Firestore which is accessible as long as a user is logged in in my application.

If an attacker creates around 100 user accounts, and writes a script which gradually and continuously access one entry from the collection with around 10~50tps each from different computers (e.g. 100 random compute instances, 1 for each user), the total number of read access per day can go over 216 million requests.

(100 users * 25 avg TPS * 86400sec/day) = 216 million.

This translates to around $129 dollars/day, with current pricing unit of $0.06/100k requests.

If attacker uses `list` request and access 10 items at once instead of just a single item, the charge can go up to $1290/day. If one of the collection allows users to query up to 100 records at once, this can become $12900/day.

I might be too paranoid about this, but I want to avoid facing $10k surprise bill which accumulated overnight and learn about it in the morning when I wake up. I know that chance of this attack happening is low, but it still seems possible for any attacker to execute it if wanted.

Because of this risk, I wouldn't ever want to expose my Firestore collection directly to client sdks (e.g. set all read/write security rules to false), and would rather want to use custom made endpoints & Firebase Admin SDK to control rate limits... but this just loses all advantages of available client sdks for reduced latency and ease in developments.

Does Firestore have some form of mechanism to prevent this kind of issue from happening? Or does it allow rate-limiting requests similar to max read/write capacity limits in AWS dynamoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Firestore, as a standalone product, doesn't have any rate limiting by default.  Google Cloud Platform, as a whole, has [configurable billing alerts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets) that apply to your entire project.  (All Firebase projects are also Google Cloud Platform projects.)

If you have a surprise bill that can't be explained, [contact Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for help resolving that.

Comment: This would be considered a major flaw. Is there any  type UX design or content model that can prevent DDOS-style attacks? I wonder if some sort of user counter in the database itself may implement some sort of rate limit mechanic, but that would require a double query for the counter and the resource ...

Comment: @TimBanon Please contact Firebase support directly about billing related questions.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: So Firebase charges by usage, but offers NO option to set hard budget limits, and provides NO protection against DDOS or other attacks by bots. The risk this represents for developers is absolutely huge!

Comment: @Sébastien I suggest sharing your concerns with Firebase support. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: indentured servitude is an asset nowadays

Comment: _I meant to edit the above crass comment with this_: that being said, I have (1) in my development made a concerted effort to rely on (2) **firestore http origin settings** in the console, with (3) **SSL certificate deployment**.  Some with CORS.  My profile has a question I asked and solved to implement CORS in a firebase / google cloud function.  Maybe in achieving (1) everything needs a `clearTimeout(this.timeout);`
`this.timeout = setTimeout(()=>{return()},900000)`

Comment: Is it possible to set a rule in Firestore that limits the rate at which a user/IP/token etc. can write into the collection? Say no more than 10 times a minute or something?