# Does Firebase Firestore have measures to stop malicious requests?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Since Firebase Firestore is priced per operation (read, write, delete), my biggest concern is someone may get their hands on a valid endpoint, to either read, write, or delete a document, and just perform this operation numerous times outside the expected scope of its use.

Are there any measures that prevent malicious requests? Like if an operation occurred 10,000 times per minute, does the user then experience some kind of lock-out or would these requests be considered legal?

I understand there are database security rules, but they seem insufficient. Sure, I can check if a user is authenticated, etc, but what is to stop a malicious user from getting authenticated, figuring out where the valid and permitted endpoints to read, write, or delete documents, and just creating a script to do that on repeat?

I also understand that I can set daily spending limits. But that would just limit the amount of money I was spending, not a malicious user who could potentially use up those limits and cause the database to stop working.

EDIT: My question is not concerned solely with billing. It is concerned with malicious users who MAY HAVE access to read/write a document AND abuse this right by writing a script that drives up the number of operations with the intent of abuse. Does Firebase have any measures to stop this or not?

And if the response is "There exists security rules" then please tell me how these security rules can be written to not allow more than 100 requests per minute from the same user or something along those lines.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60720708/firestore-billing-usage-api) out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore billing & USage API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60720708/firestore-billing-usage-api)

Comment: *what is to stop a malicious user...* those would the the database rules. As the developer you have complete control over what a user can or cannot read/write to. For example, if you were a malicious user and authenticated, Rules would prevent you from reading/writing my data an only allow you to access your own data. Maybe if you can clarify what you're asking and provide a use case we may be able to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: @AlexMamo How does that link answer my question?

Comment: @Jay, imagine a situation where a user is permitted to access a document, what is to say that user will not be malicious and abuse this privilege by hitting the server in ways that are unanticipated? This isn't a matter of `request.auth.uid == userId`, its a matter of a user meeting those requirements but hitting the server needlessly.

Comment: What does *hitting the server in ways that are unanticipated* mean? If you give a user permission to access a node, then they have access to the data in that node. If you deny write access then they cannot write. *Like if an operation occurred 10,000 times per minute* sounds like a DDOS vector so see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56823965/does-firestore-have-internal-mechanism-to-protect-app-from-excessive-charge-fr)

Comment: @Jay, Something like a DDOS vector is what I meant. Thank you for that. Maybe I am being paranoid, but isn't this fairly common? Even if you had strict rules for who had permission to read or write to a node, when they have that permission can't they perform something like a DDOS vector? And capping your spending does little to address this problem, it just means someone can eat up your spending limits and deny other users from using the database/service after the fact.

Comment: There's very little that can be done to *prevent* an attack as if data is readable, it can be read repeatedly. Just like a website; attacks can't be directly stopped but the effect can be somewhat mitigated but it can be an inconvenience to users. With Firebase, you can cap the charges to reduce your exposure and if it does happen, notify them so they can take action on their end. That being said, think about the big picture; is a nefarious user really going to sign up for an app and attack it? You're not being paranoid and asking a good question but don't spend a lot of time on it.

Comment: Help me in this scenario if firebase.json got leaked to hackers or public.Need  solution to this to stop accesyto firestore, If we delete the firebase web app from apps list and delete Oath (API&cred console) firebase auth stopped working, but firestore still readable with deleted web json configeration. , how to make firestore Stop working websdk when firebase.json keys and api oath got deleted?

Answer (score 4):

First, I feel the need to clarify that I love Firebase. But... this is probably one of the most annoying aspects of it. I feel this should come solved out of the box in the form of a configurable threshold per user.

With that said. IMHO you have only 2 viable options:

#### Option 1: Cloud Function

This is the easy answer and it defeats the main advantages of Firestore. So I wont dig deep here. Just know that it would be a valid option to create a cloud function endpoint and validate or block requests based on your backend logic.

#### Option 2: Firestore Rules

The only way (that I could discover) to solve malicious user behavior is to keep a counter of operations by user.

- First you need to setup a cloud function that listens to write operations on the collection you want to protect.
- Then create a private document for the user, counting write actions performed on the collection.
- Write a rule that will block users with high amounts of writes in the past hour for example.

This will obviously incur in extra costs for the cloud function, the extra writes to keep the counters and the extra reads used to get the private document with the counter in the security rules validation.